# Degenerate Beltrami equation and inverse

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, teichmuller-theory, quasiconformal

The Beltrami equation $f_{\bar{z}}=\mu(z)f_{z}$ is degenerate when $\left \| \mu \right \|_{\infty}=1$. For these equations, Lehto and David among others have given conditions for existence. The Lehto condition is that the distortion satisfies $K\in L_{1,loc}(\mathbb{C})$ and

$$\int_{[0,1]} \frac{1}{\int_{[0,2\pi]} K(z+\rho e^{i\theta}d\theta }\frac{d\rho}{\rho}=\infty$$

for all $z\in \mathbb{C}$ and the David condition is $$m(|\mu(z)|>1-\varepsilon)\leq a \exp(-b /\varepsilon)$$

for some constants $a$, $b$.

> Q: what is known about whether $f^{-1}$ is also a solution for degenerate BE? For which conditions has this questions been explored (what about for Lehto)?

For example, in David's paper: if we instead have

$$m(|\mu(z)|>1-\varepsilon)\leq a \exp(-b e^{c/\varepsilon}),$$

for some constants $a$, $b$, $c$, then the inverse is also a solution to a Beltrami equation:
$$f_{\bar{z}}^{-1}=\widetilde{\mu}(z)f_{z}^{-1},$$ 
where $\widetilde{\mu}(z):=\mu(f^{-1}(z))$.

Update: An idea is to fatten up the circular integral

$$\int_{[0,2\pi]} K_{F^{-1}}(z+\rho e^{i\theta}d\theta\leq \int_{(S_{r})_{\varepsilon}} K_{F^{-1}}(w)dw,$$
where $(S_{r})_{\varepsilon}$ is a neighbourhood of the circle $S_{r}$. Then by change of variables for $K_{F^{-1}}:=K_{F}(F^{-1})$ we obtain

$$\int_{(S_{r})_{\varepsilon}} K_{F^{-1}}(w)dw\leq \int_{F^{-1}((S_{r})_{\varepsilon})} K_{F}(w)J_{F}(w)dw.$$

Now the problem becomes of obtaining a sublinear growth for the above integral.